# Printing Tags in mp3 useing python, eyed3

Tags: python, eyed3

I'm trying to print Tags from mp3 files.
But I can't find any ways to do it.

```
 import eyeD3
 tag = eyeD3.Tag()
 tag.link("/some/file.mp3")
 print tag.getArtist()
 print tag.getAlbum()
 print tag.getTitle()
```

I used this code, and it it didn't work.
Is there any way to fix this or any other way to print tags using eyed3?